# How to get old version of Redmine to read new Ruby Gems path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

We at one point tried to upgrade to Redmine 2.2, from 1.1, but we missed certain plugins so we decided to go back to Redmine 1.3. But something about the old setup is reading from the wrong Gems path.

If I do this:

ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"

I get:

["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global"]

but when I cd to the directory where we have Redmine installed, and I do this:

passenger start -p 80

I get:

*** Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/bind_visitor))

I was previously getting:

*** Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter))

but I fixed that with this:

cp /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb  /home/lawrence/redmine-2.2/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/

then I got this error:

*** Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter))

and I fixed that by doing this:

cp /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb  /home/lawrence/redmine-2.2/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/

but I can not fix the current problem that way.

If I do this:

find /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/         -name *bind_visitor*

then I see this:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/arel-3.0.2/test/visitors/test_bind_visitor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/doc/arel-3.0.2/rdoc/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor_rb.html

but I have no location that I can copy that to.

If I do this:

ls -al   /home/lawrence/redmine-2.2/vendor/rails

I see:

actionmailer
 actionpack
 activerecord
 activeresource
 activesupport
 railties

There is no gems/arel-3.0.2 to copy to here.

I tried:

cp -r /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/arel-3.0.2/    vendor/rails/

mv vendor/rails/arel-3.0.2/  vendor/rails/arel

and I did chown and chgrp (since I was working as root) and then I stopped Phusion Passenger (standalone) and restarted it:

passenger start -p 80

but I still got the same error:

*** Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/bind_visitor)) (process 11636, thread #):
    from /home/lawrence/redmine-2.2/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `rescue in rescue in establish_connection'

So I think at this point I'll have to do the "right" thing and figure out why Passenger/Ruby/Rails is reading from the wrong path.

Any suggestions?

rails -v
Rails 3.2.12

ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]

gem -v
1.8.25

CentOS 6

I have placed a Gemfile in this installation of Redmine, even though Redmine 1.3 came out before bundler had come into widespread use -- I don't think Redmine depended on Gemfile or bundler till 1.4.

The Gemfile:

## file: /var/www/redmine/Gemfile

source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "rake", "0.8.3"
gem "rack", "1.1.0"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"
gem "rubytree", "0.5.2", :require => "tree"
gem "RedCloth", "~>4.2.3", :require => "redcloth" # for CodeRay
gem "mysql2"
gem "coderay", "~>0.9.7"

This I copied from some StackOverflow q/a that I saw about Redmine.

The gem list still includes all the stuff I had installed for Redmine 2.2:

gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
actionpack (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activemodel (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activerecord-mysql-adapter (0.0.1)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activesupport (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
afm (0.2.0)
arel (3.0.2)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bourne (1.3.0, 1.1.2)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.2.3)
coderay (1.0.9, 1.0.8, 0.9.8)
daemon_controller (1.1.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hashery (2.1.0)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
hoe (3.7.0, 1.5.1)
holidays (1.0.5, 1.0.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1, 0.4.2)
icalendar (1.2.1)
io-console (0.4.1, 0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1, 2.0.3)
json (1.8.0, 1.7.7, 1.7.6, 1.5.4)
json_pure (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3, 2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.23, 1.21, 1.20.1)
minitest (4.6.0, 2.5.1)
mocha (0.13.2, 0.13.0, 0.12.3, 0.10.5)
multi_json (1.7.7, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0)
mysql (2.9.1, 2.9.0)
mysql2 (0.3.13, 0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
open-uri-cached (0.0.5)
passenger (3.0.19)
pdf-reader (1.3.1, 1.3.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prawn (0.12.0)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.1.0)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
railties (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
rake (10.1.0, 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2, 0.8.3)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12.1, 3.9.5)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
rmagick (2.13.2)
ruby-openid (2.2.2, 2.1.8)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubytree (0.5.2)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
shoulda (3.3.2, 2.11.3)
shoulda-context (1.0.2)
shoulda-matchers (1.4.2)
simplecov (0.7.1)
simplecov-html (0.7.1)
sprockets (2.8.2, 2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.5.4, 1.2.3)
thor (0.18.1, 0.17.0)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.14, 1.4.12)
ttfunk (1.0.3)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.35)
yard (0.8.6.2, 0.8.4.1)
```

Comment: What about asking to the redmine guys? http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/boards

Comment: I did but those forums are mostly dead. I've asked 3 or 4 questions there and only 1 of them ever got an answer. Also, I am pretty sure this is a straight Ruby/Rails question -- it does not really involve Redmine at all. This, I think, a question about paths.